# script task in SSIS to import excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, ssis

I have reviewed the questions that may have had my answer and unfortunately they don't seem to apply.  Here is my situation.  I have to import worksheets from my client.  In columns A, C, D, and AA the client has the information I need.  The balance of the columns have what to me is worthless information.  The column headers are consistent in the four columns I need, but are very inconsistent in the columns that don't matter.  For example cell A1 contains Division.  This is true across all of the spreadsheets.  Cell B1 can contain anything from sleeve length to overall length to fit.  What I need to do is to import only the columns I need and map them to an SQL 2008 R2 table.  I have defined the table in a stored procedure which is currently calling an SSIS function.

The problem is that when I try to import a spreadsheet that has different column names the SSIS fails and I have to go back in an run it manually to get the fields set up right.

I cannot imagine that what I am trying to do has not been done before.  Just so the magnitude is not lost, I have 170 users who have over 120 different spreadsheet templates.

I am desperate for a workable solution.  I can do everything after getting the file into my table in SQL.  I have even written the code to move the files back to the FTP server.

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem really is. If you always load columns A, C, D and AA then the column "names" (I guess you mean the data in the first row?) shouldn't matter because you can just refer to them by position (number), not name. If this doesn't help, please clarify what you mean by a "column name".

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking.  How do I refer to the column number instead of the first row.  I have never done that.  In every other case where I have used this kind of functionality, I imported everything and then selected the pertinent information in SQL.  Is there a tutorial that shows how to import specific columns from an excel spreadsheet into SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I put together a post describing how I've used a [Script task to parse Excel](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html). It's allowe me to import decidedly non-tabular data into a data flow.

The core concept is that you will use a the JET or ACE provider and simply query the data out of an Excel Worksheet/named range. Once you have that, you have a dataset you can walk through row-by-row and perform whatever logic you need. In your case, you can skip row 1 for the header and then only import columns A, C, D and AA.

That logic would go in the ExcelParser class. So, the Foreach loop on line 71 would probably be distilled down to something like (code approximate)

```
// This gets the value of column A
current = dr[0].ToString();
// this assigns the value of current into our output row at column 0
newRow[0] = current;

// This gets the value of column C
current = dr[2].ToString();
// this assigns the value of current into our output row at column 1
newRow[1] = current;

// This gets the value of column D
current = dr[3].ToString();
// this assigns the value of current into our output row at column 2
newRow[2] = current;

// This gets the value of column AA
current = dr[26].ToString();
// this assigns the value of current into our output row at column 3
newRow[3] = current;
```

You obviously might need to do type conversions and such here but that's core of the parsing logic.

Comment: I would like to take this offline to understand what is going on.  I am very much struggling with getting this information in correctly.  Would there be a way to accomplish that?