# Looking for efficient methods of loading large excel (xlsx) files into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv, ssis

I'm looking for alternate data import solutions.  Currently my process is as follows:

1. Open a large xlsx file in excel
2. Replace all "|" (pipes) with a space or another unique character
3. Save the file as pipe-delimited CSV
4. Use the import wizard in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to import the CSV file

The process works; however, steps 1-3 take a long time since the files being loaded are extremely large (approx. 1 million records).

Based on some research, I've found a few potential solutions:
a) Bulk Import - This unfortunately does not eliminate steps 1-3 mentioned above since the files need to be converted to a flat (or CSV) format
b) OpenRowSet/OpenDataSource - There are 2 issues with this problem.  First, it takes a long time to load (about 2 hours for a million records).  Second, when I try to load many files at once (about 20 file each containing 1 million records), I receive an "out-of-memory" error

I haven't tried SSIS; I've heard it has issues with large xlsx files

So this leads to my question.   Are there any solutions/alternate options out there that will make importing of large excel files faster?

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I have to ask a stupid question. Does the data actually originate in an excel file, or it the excel file some generated output that you could get before it becomes an excel file. I think you will have more flexibility in non-Excel formats

Comment: That's shockingly bad performance on `OPENROWSET`, I use it frequently and not encountered performance as slow as yours (also running multiples). Why are you doing steps 1-3 and not just using the import wizard in SSMS to import the excel file?

Comment: Here's another stupid question - if you are removing all the pipes why are you saving it as a pipe delimited file?

Comment: @Rikalous remove pipes from within fields, add them in between fields on saving to use as delimiter. Instead of using text-qualifier. (I assume)

Comment: I agree with Gary - someone probably has to spend hours unecessarily creating that Excel file. I'm sure you've already gone down this path, but what options do you have for getting it in CSV already?

Comment: A little late, but - have you considered using .NET with SqlBulkCopy? I've used it combined with the ACE OLEDB driver to load XLSX files as DataSets and copy them to dynamically-created tables. This resulted in a high-performance, flexible import system.

Answer (score 2):

I love Excel as a data visualization tool but it's pants as a data transport layer. My preference is to either query it with the [JET/ACE driver](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-excel-in-ssis-lookup.html) or use C# for [non-tabular data](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html).

I haven't cranked it up to the millions but I'd have to believe the first approach would have to be faster than your current simply based on the fact that you do not have to perform double reads and writes for your data.

- [Excel Source as Lookup Transformation Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953531/excel-source-as-lookup-transformation-connection)
- [script task in SSIS to import excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980580/script-task-in-ssis-to-import-excel-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

Something I have done before (and I bring up because I see your file type is XLSX, not XLS) is open the file though winzip, pull the XML data out, then import it.  Starting in 2007, the XLSX file is really a zip file with many folders/files in it.  if the excel file is simple (not a lot of macros, charts, formating, etc), you can just pull the data from the XML file that is in the background.  I know you can see it through WINZIP, I dont know about other compression apps.

Comment: Do you have a blog post or an example of this approach? I'm always interested in seeing new ways of handling problems

Comment: Sorry, no blog.  If you open it in Winzip and fish around, you will see the XML files. The name of files/folders depend on your worksheet names and they have some internal files names too.

Comment: BTW, you could try to save the excel file as XML or fixed width instead so you dont have to remove the PIKE's from the file.  One less step anyway.

Comment: I'd likely just unzip it in memory using the .net libraries but was hoping to hear specifics around the xml parsing

Comment: Here is a link to some info on saving fixed width: http://superuser.com/questions/100433/export-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-fixed-width-text-file