# SSIS import an excel file with multiple header rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Newbie doing SSIS import of csv and excel files.  Things have been going well until I ran into an excel file with multiple header rows.  The number of rows between the headers varies.  I only need to import the rows between two of the rows based on the value in column 1.  Just say I only need to read the data between Role and Work Item  I have no idea where to even start on this one. Here is a small sample of the data.

```
Work Items
1
2
Primary Data View
5
6
7
8
Priority
11
12
13
Role
15
23
22
12
Work Item
12
45
Actor Items
55
22
33
52
```

Comment: Nothing out of the box is going to accomplish this. You are going to be writing code to deal with this, that or dump the whole thing to a table but even then it may not go as well as you'd hope depending on the shape of your data. You're welcome to make what you can of my approach [SSIS Excel Source via Script](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html) which stems from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990184/181965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided I assume the source file and filter records would be different. I would say extract all the data into a staging table. Now do a transform query on the staging table to filter on required criteria and lastly would load only the filtered records into the target table.

Comment: Thank you I will give the staging a table a try